# What can trigger the "Getting Windows ready" screen at shutdown?

Tags: windows-10, windows-update

I have a Windows 10 Enterprise image that I have made sure to disable Windows Update, however I still get complaints from users that they sometimes see that "Getting Windows ready" screen. So aside from Windows Update and turning Windows features on/off, is there anything else that can bring that screen up?
EDIT: I'm sure that Windows Update service is in *disabled* state at any time, so I'm not looking for ways to disable Windows Update again.

Comment: I don't see this as a duplicate at all.

Comment: Legitimate question: How are your workstations receiving updates?

Comment: They _won't_ receive update. Those workstations are for special purposes, not for normal daily usage so there is no risk involved here.

Comment: These local users or AD users?

Comment: Local users, no AD configured.